# ts-jest: Import MockedObject type

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

How do I import the type `MockedObject` into my test file? My code example is as below

```ts
import { mocked, MockedObject } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import someFunction from '../src/common/someFunction';
import SomeClass from '../src/model/SomeClass';
import SomeInterface from '../src/interface/SomeInterface';

jest.mock('../src/model/SomeClass');

describe('run test', () => {
  let mockValidators: any;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    mockedValidators = (await someFunction()).map((v: SomeInterface) =>
      mocked(v)
    ):
  }
})
```

I tried to import `MockedObject` from ts-jest/utils but VSCode cannot find it. I want to replace `any` with `MockedObject<SomeInterface>`.

Error:

> Module '"../../../node_modules/ts-jest/utils"' has no exported member 'MockedObject'.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/master/src/utils/testing.ts#L17), we can see `ts-jest/utils` does NOT export `MockedObject` type. You can copy the types from `ts-jest/dist/util/testing.d.ts` file, add them to your project.

E.g.

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

interface SomeInterface {
  validate(): boolean;
}
declare type MockableFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;
declare type MethodKeysOf<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends MockableFunction ? K : never;
}[keyof T];
declare type PropertyKeysOf<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends MockableFunction ? never : K;
}[keyof T];
declare type ArgumentsOf<T> = T extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : never;
declare type ConstructorArgumentsOf<T> = T extends new (...args: infer A) => any ? A : never;
interface MockWithArgs<T extends MockableFunction> extends jest.MockInstance<ReturnType<T>, ArgumentsOf<T>> {
  new (...args: ConstructorArgumentsOf<T>): T;
  (...args: ArgumentsOf<T>): ReturnType<T>;
}
declare type MaybeMockedConstructor<T> = T extends new (...args: any[]) => infer R ? jest.MockInstance<R, ConstructorArgumentsOf<T>> : {};
declare type MockedFunction<T extends MockableFunction> = MockWithArgs<T> &
  {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K];
  };
declare type MockedObject<T> = MaybeMockedConstructor<T> &
  {
    [K in MethodKeysOf<T>]: T[K] extends MockableFunction ? MockedFunction<T[K]> : T[K];
  } &
  {
    [K in PropertyKeysOf<T>]: T[K];
  };

const UserValidator: SomeInterface = {
  validate: () => true,
};

async function someFunction() {
  return [UserValidator];
}

describe('run test', () => {
  let mockedValidators: Array<MockedObject<SomeInterface>>;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    mockedValidators = (await someFunction()).map((v: SomeInterface) => mocked(v));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible (since [this](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/2086) feature was merged) to access ts-jest types (tested with version 26.5.5).

See this example:

```
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import { MockedObject } from 'ts-jest/dist/utils/testing';

let myMock: MockedObject<SomeInterface>;
...
myMock = mocked(new SomeClass());
```